# Why are downloaded files only editable when I run gedit as root?

Tags: permissions, downloads, gedit

First of all: I'm just starting with ubuntu other than "quick one time use in a virtual machine".

Well I fully appreciate the fact that there's a big difference between running as root and running as "another user"; also for editing system files.

However this "gets annoying" when it continuous to user files. Just now I downloaded a text file. Firefox allows me to quickly open it using gedit; nice/expected.

I do so: however the file is opened in "read only" mode.

Why? - And how can I change it so that my downloads don't require root privilege to be edited?

Comment: Are you running Firefox as root? Or did you select to directly open the file instead of saving it? In that case, the file is only stored in a temporary location and made read-only, as it will be discarded as soon as you close the browser, or at least once you reboot. You have to save the download directly and open later, or open directly and then save a copy of it somewhere.

Comment: One can't edit in the temporary location just to have "quick edits" of small files that are supposed to undergo download -> edit -> email edited version?

Comment: I don't know how you want to "email edited version" - you can still save the file in any other location (e.g. your Downloads or Documents folder) and use that as attachment for your email. Or regularly download/save the file and open and edit it there, as I said. You have to pick one. The "open with" option in the download dialogue is mainly intended as "view once and throw away".